# edit model instance in django

Tags: python, django

I have seen a number of posts about this, and I suspect something is off in my template?  I'm getting a redirect to the correct url , but the page doesn't have any data on it.  I've read the docs, and looked at multiple SO questions, and I'm clearly missing something.

Clicking the edit button redirects to the url that seems correct - for example, clicking `'edit'` on the fourth item displayed redirects me to  `/edit_item/5/` but the page is blank, so it may be a problem in the form or template?

**Here's my form:**

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'start_date': forms.widgets.SelectDateWidget(),
            'end_date': forms.widgets.SelectDateWidget()
        }
```

**Here's my view:**

```
def edit_item(request, item_id):
    this_item = items.objects.get(pk=item_id)
    form = MyModelForm(instance=this_item)
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST, instance=this_item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('itemsbydate.html')
    else:
        form = MyModelForm(instance=this_item)
    return render_to_response('itemsbydate.html', {
        'item_id':item_id, 'form':form, 'this_item':this_item
    }, RequestContext(request))
```

**And the `itemsbydate.html` file:**

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.start_date}}</td>
        <td>{{item.end_date}}</td>
        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
        <td>{{item.category}}</td>
        <td>
            <form action="/edit_item/{{item_id.id}}/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" value="edit item">
            </form>
        </td>
{% endfor %}
```

**And my `urls.py`:**

```
  url(r'^edit_item/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.edit_item, name='edit_item'),
```

Comment: Well you're not passing anything called `items` to your template for starters. Is your model actually called `items`?

Comment: thanks. no, it wasn't, and i've corrected the oversight in the question.

Comment: Think we need to see your `edit_item` template.

Comment: What is `item_id.id` in the template? Also, it is better and less error prone to use `form action="{% url 'edit_item' item.id %}"` instead of hard coding it like `form action="/edit_item/{{item_id.id}}/"`.

Comment: You're still not passing anything named `items` to your template. What are you expecting `items` to be?